# VUE js call a child component method in a different component hierarchy

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have this following vuejs component hierarchy.
What i want to do it to invoke **COMP_B_ONE validate()** method, when **COMP_A_TWO submit()** method is invoked EVERY TIME.

```
MAIN_COMPONENT
              COMP_A_ONE
                    COMP_B_ONE
                          validate()
                    COMP_B_TWO
                          validate()
              COMP_A_TWO
                    submit()
```

I've already implemented an emit when submit is triggered in **COMP_A_TWO**   which can be listened in **MAIN_COMPONENT**

```
submit() {
  this.$emit('submit')
}
```

what seems to be the best approach in this regard? any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: You can use an event bus to communicate sibling components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can get this done by two ways.

1 - **Global `EventBus`**
I will create an eventBus and register events on it from any file and listen it anywhere -

```
import { EventBus } from '@/eventBus' 
// simply import it to component which need listen the event


//Register Event where you have your methods - like In your COMP_B_TWO                   
 EventBus.$on('validate', () => { this.validate() })

// Emit event from another component
EventBus.$emit('validate')// Like directly from your COMP_A_TWO
```

To know how to create a eventBus follow this - [Global Event Bus Vue](https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/)

---

Another way I can think is

2 - **Refs**

Add reference to `COMP_A_ONE` like

```
<COMP_A_ONE ref = "one" />
```

Then add reference to `COMP_B_ONE`

```
<COMP_B_ONE ref = "b-one" />
```

Now when you trigger `submit` from `main component`

execute it -

```
this.$on('submit', () => {
  this.$refs.one['b-one'].validate()
})
```

It totally depends which way you wanna go -

- If you need to call `validate` for many more places, I would suggest choosing `EventBus`
- You just need current component to have it, use `Refs`

Comment: prefer the eventBus approach. Works well.

Comment: Happy to help :) Mark answer as accepted if you feel it works as per your all requirements. Thanks