# How to passing the data to another component in vue js

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I created a career page which is when user select the title of the position that they apply, it will redirect into application form and it will display the title of the position. If they are interested to apply for the position they will enter some input which is their full name, contact and cv. Once they submitted the application, it will send the data into the server include the position that they already applied.

Header.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1 class="title-wrapper">
      Application Form
    </h1>
    <p class="info-wrapper">
      You are applying as
      <nuxt-link to="/careers">
        <u>{{ title }}</u>
      </nuxt-link>
    </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Header',
  props: {
    title: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Form.vue

```
<form class="app-form" @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
  <InputField
    v-model="fullName"
    label="Full Name"
    firequired
    required
    placeholder="Your full name"
    @handleChange="handleChangeName($event)"
  />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Application.vue (Parent)

```
<div class="contact-wrapper">
  <Intro :title="title" />
  <Form />
</div>
```

The validation for submit the form is inside the Form.vue, how to send the title from Header.vue into Form.vue and send it into the server. This is what I've tried

Form.vue

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Submit',
  template: '<nuxt-link to="/careers"><u>{{ title }}</u></nuxt-link>',
  methods: {
    onSubmit() {
      this.$axios.post('url', {
        position:this.title
      })
   }
};
</script>
```

And it returns nothing

Comment: You can use `store` to share the props between components.

Comment: you can follow [this](https://vegibit.com/vue-sibling-component-communication) doc to know how to sibling component communicate each other.

Comment: If you `Application.vue` is able to pass the title props to the header, why not just pass title props tot theform as well?

Comment: I have answered a similar question, hope this helps you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56336049/vue-js-call-a-child-component-method-in-a-different-component-hierarchy/56336233#56336233